# Flutter: Error running pod install and error launching application on iPhone 15

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
        WARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
        Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

        export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:167:in `unicode_normalize'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:167:in `installation_root'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:227:in `podfile_path'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:105:in `markdown_podfile'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:30:in `report'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/pod:25:in `load'
        from /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/3.2.0/unicode_normalize/normalize.rb:141:in `normalize': Unicode Normalization not appropriate for ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:167:in `unicode_normalize'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:167:in `installation_root'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:227:in `podfile_path'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/config.rb:206:in `podfile'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:160:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
        from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.14.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/pod:25:in `load'
        from /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 15.


Error running pod install and Error launching application on iPhone 15.
```

Comment: We [expect more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from a question on Stack Overflow than a terminal dump.